# Sum of SQL columns in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a SQL table as follows:

```
+---+--------+------------+
|ID | AMOUNT | PRODUCT_ID |
+---+---------------------+
|1  | 100    | 5          |
|2  | 100    | 5          |
|3  | 100    | 5          |
|4  | 100    | 10         |
|5  | 100    | 10         |
|6  | 100    | 10         |
|7  | 100    | 10         | 
+---+--------+------------+
```

I'm using codeigniter and expecting to get the `SUM OF AMOUNTS` according to the `PRODUCT_ID` dynamically. the required output is:

```
sum of product_id 5 = 300
sum of product_id 10 = 400
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you have asked exactly the same question earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956441/sql-sum-of-columns-in-codeigniter and accepted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `SUM` like this:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product_id;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/930040/1)**:

```
| product_id | TotalAmount |
|------------|-------------|
|          5 |         300 |
|         10 |         400 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY with SUM with COUNT as well:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount, COUNT(product_id) as Count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Results:

```
| product_id | TotalAmount | Count |
|------------|-------------|-------|
|          5 |         300 |    3  |
|         10 |         400 |    4  |
```

Answer (score 0):

By using GROUP_BY product_id and sum

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product_id;
```